# How to expose user passwords in the most "secure" way in django?

Tags: python, django, passwords, password-encryption

I am working on Django 1.9 project and I have been asked to enable some users to print a page with a list of a set of users and their passwords.
Of course passwords are encrypted and there is no out-of-the-box ways of doing this.
I know this would imply a security breach so my question is kind of contradictory, but is there any logical way of doing this that doesn't imply a huge security breach in the software?

Comment: If you need more information maybe try this here : http://security.stackexchange.com/ They have some question already on your topic maybe give it a read? In short, no you should never be able to print a User setted password. If it's a default password that wouldn't be an issue like the standard birthday+id number. wim covers the rest that I want to say.

Comment: You shouldn't. this request makes no sense and it should be illegal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no logical way of doing this that doesn't imply a huge security breach in the software.

If the passwords are stored correctly (salted and hashed), then even site admins with unrestricted access on the database can not tell you what the passwords are in plain text.

You should push back against this unreasonable request.  If you have a working "password reset" functionality, then nobody but the user ever needs to know a user's password.  **If you don't have a reliable "password reset" feature, then try and steer the conversation and development effort in this direction**.  There is rarely any real business need for knowing/printing user passwords, and these kind of feature requests may be coming from non-technical people who have misunderstandings (or no understanding) about the implementation detail of authentication and authorization.

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.